# Como criar um array com dados de <input> com checkbox assinalados?

Tags: php, array, checkbox

Com esse script, escrito resumido pois vocês sabem melhor que eu.

```
<?php
$query = "select from table where status='0'";

$i=0; 
while (mysqli_fetch_array)

echo '<input type="hidden" value="' . $num_compra . '" name="item['.$i.'][num_compra]" />
<input type="hidden" value="'.$plano.'" name="item['.$i.'][plano]">';
$i++;
?>
```

consegui isso:

```
<html>
<input type="hidden" value="1111" name="item[0][num_compra]" />
<input type="hidden" value="aaaa" name="item[0][plano]" >

<input type="hidden" value="2222" name="item[1][num_compra]" />
<input type="hidden" value="bbbb" name="item[1][plano]" >

<input type="hidden" value="3333" name="item[2][num_compra]" />
<input type="hidden" value="cccc" name="item[2][plano]" >

quantidade de pares de input de acordo com o banco de dados.

<input type="submit">
</html>
```

Após o SUBMIT:

```
echo $_POST['item'];
Array ( [0] => Array ( [num_compra] => 1111 [plano] => aaaa ) 
    [1] => Array ( [num_compra] => 2222 [plano] => bbbb )
    [2] => Array ( [num_compra] => 3333 [plano] => cccc ) )
```

Até aqui, tudo bem, **agora o problema**: preciso colocar um checkbox para cada input

```
<input type="hidden" value="1111" name="item[0][num_compra]" />
<input type="hidden" value="aaaa" name="item[0][plano]" >
<INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" NAME="????" VALUE="?????"> CHECKBOX 1

<input type="hidden" value="2222" name="item[1][num_compra]" />
<input type="hidden" value="bbbb" name="item[1][plano]" >
<INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" NAME="?????" VALUE="?????"> CHECKBOX 2

<input type="hidden" value="3333" name="item[2][num_compra]" />
<input type="hidden" value="cccc" name="item[2][plano]" >
<INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" NAME="?????" VALUE="????"> CHECKBOX 3
```

e criar um array somente com os checkbox=checked

```
CHECKBOX 3 checked
Array ( [0] => Array ( [num_compra] => 3333 [plano] => cccc ) )
```

CHECKBOX 2 e CHECKBOX 3 checked

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [num_compra] => 2222 [plano] => bbbb )
        [1] => Array ( [num_compra] => 3333 [plano] => cccc ) )
```

CHECKBOX 1 e CHECKBOX 3

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [num_compra] => 1111 [plano] => aaaa ) 
        [1] => Array ( [num_compra] => 3333 [plano] => cccc ) )
```

e no final, utilizar este array para fazer

```
UPDATE table SET status='1' WHERE num_compra = $num_compra AND plano = $plano;
```

Qual a solução para isso?

Comment: Pode explicar melhor?

Comment: minha duvida eh:
qual name e value que devo atribuir aos checkbox e como escrever o script php para criar o array com os dados de cada checkbox marcado?
Atualmente, eu consigo um array com TODOS os dados, mesmo que nao tenha marcado o checkbox.

Answer (score 3):

Se usar o mesmo nome para esses inputs e com `[]`, então no PHP vai ter uma array com os checkbox que estiverem marcados.

Ou seja:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="?????"> checkbox 1
```

Assim no PHP pode usar `$chgeckboxes = $_POST['checkbox'];` que vai ser uma array.

O value é só atribuir o valor que precisa no lado do PHP, tem de ser você a escolher. Ou um booleano ou por exemplo um preço ou o numero do produto. Depende daquilo que quer.

Comment: Sergio, vc quis dizer assim?  


    `<input type="hidden" value="1111" name="item[0][num_compra]" />`
    `<input type="hidden" value="aaaa" name="item[0][plano]" >` 
    `<INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" NAME="checkbox[]" VALUE="qualquer">` CHECKBOX 1....
    um print_r em $chgeckboxes me deu um resultado assim: Array ( [0] => qualquer)

Comment: to penando pra formatar o texto

Comment: @ClaudioNishi dê uma olhada aqui: http://sergiofrilans.se/temp/test.php e para formatar o HTML aqui use plicas ou seja --> ` <-- e sem espaços antes nem depois.

Comment: obrigado, @sergio...

infelizmente nao consegui fazer funcionar, continua vindo todos os inputs.
Resolvi fazendo com GET mesmo. Como se trata de uma pagina onde soh o adm acessa, acho que nao dara problema, tomando as devidas precaucoes no script.

Comment: @ClaudioNishi viste o meu link de exemplo? no link faz o que procuras?